# In LSTM, each features is applied to separate weights or shared weights?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Let's say my dataset has 6 features such as air temperature, evaporation, pumping rates, soil temperature, humidity, and wind speed. When I feed it to LSTM, they'll be applied to different weights or the same weight?

Assume that the step is merely one.